# How to getElementsByName when looping through the names?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a table with field that appends when I click on add row. I want to be able to getElementsByName and insert a Price value from the database to each field when row is appended and Item is selected.

***Appended Rows***

```js
let int=0;
function addRow() {

  var tr = '<tr>' + '<td class="forhead" style="white-space:nowrap;" width="20"><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></td>' +
    '<td class="forhead" style="white-space:nowrap;" width="80"><input type="number"  name="items[' + (int) + '][inv_quantity]" id="qty[]"  onkeyup="getValues()" style="width: 70px" class="form-control" onBlur=""></td>' +
    '<td><select name="items[' + (int) + '][inv_item]" class="form-control item" onChange="pDescription()" >@foreach($product_dup as $dup_product)<option>{{$dup_product->pdt_name}}</option>@endforeach</select></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" name="items[' + (int) + '][inv_desc]" class="form-control description" id="product_desc"></td>' +
    '<td class="forhead" style="white-space:nowrap;" width="150"><input type="text"  name="items[' + (int) + '][inv_price]" id="rate[]" onKeyUp="getValues()" class="form-control" value=""></td>' +
    '<td class="forhead" style="white-space:nowrap;" width="80"><input type="text"  name="items[' + (int) + '][inv_total]" id="amt[]" onKeyUp="getValues()"  class="form-control" value=""></td>' +
    '<td width="80" align="right" class="forhead" style="white-space:nowrap;"><select name="items[' + (int) + '][inv_tax]" style="width:80px" onChange="getValues()" class="form-control"><option value="0">Select</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="12.5">12.5</option></select></td>' +
    '<td class="forhead" style="white-space:nowrap;" width="80"><input type="text"  name="vat_amt[]" id="vat_amt[]" class="form-control"></td>' +
    '</tr>';
  $('tbody').append(tr);
  int++;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" ><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Row</button></span>

<table><tbody></tbody></table>
```

***Ajax Request***

```
      var int = 0 ;
      function pDescription() {
        var getDescription = document.getElementById('product_value');
        var id = getDescription.value
            $.ajax({
              url: '/get-description/'+id,
              dataType: 'JSON',
              type: 'GET',
              success: function (data) {
                document.getElementsByName("items['+ (int) +'][inv_price]")[0].value = data
                
              },
              error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            }
            });
         getValues();
      }
```

```
 document.getElementsByName("items['+ (int) +'][inv_price]")[0].value = data
```

is not working for me. Please how do I correctly do this?

Comment: `name` is a custom attribute to `td`, `gEBN` collects only elements having `name` as native property (form control elements and window elements). Use `document.querySelectorAll` and an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors), or rather a class instead of `name`.

Comment: Please is the a way to go about it? am a begging in JS

Comment: please this the error am getting ```Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=`[${int}][${inv_price}]]```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your IDs must be unique or don't use them. Use a class
2. Use the jQuery you have anyway:

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  const $parentRow = $(this).closest("tr")
  const id = $parentRow.find("whateverhastheID").data("id"); // ... data-id="theIdYouNeed"
  
  $.ajax({
    url: '/get-description/' + id,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      $parentRow.find(".someClass").value=data;
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```